# Doing something on discord.py ratelimit

Tags: python, discord.py, rate-limiting

I have a Discord bot running on the cloud, and when my shared IP hits the rate limit of 50 requests per second, my bot gets blocked for a while (I know, it's a terrible system but it's where I'm at). In the event that this happens, I want it to send me a message on another site. I have a way to send the message (with the Tweepy module for Twitter) that works, but nothing happens when I use the following code:

```
@client.event
    async def on_error(ctx, error):
      if isinstance(error, discord.errors.HTTPException):
        #do something
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since your ratelimit can only be triggered by certain commands and you only get the message in the console afterwards it makes sense to use the `on_command_error` event.

**Look at the following code:**

```py
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, discord.HTTPException):
        await ctx.send("You are ratelimited") # Send whatever you want.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try to implement this tomorrow! Is there any equivalent for ratelimits using on_message as well?

Comment: @GenerousJJ What do you mean by that?

Comment: Part of my bot listens for new messages with the on_message param, is there any way for it to handle ratelimit errors when reading server messages?